# Getting actual keycode for ibus settings

Tags: c++, c, linux, ime

I am able to read the ibus keys configuration to know the keys that trigger an engine ON/OFF (accessible via the property "general/hotkey" and "trigger"). that is all good but that returns lists of strings (gchar*) which combination switches ON/OFF the IME (ex: ["SHIFT+CTRL+F9", "SHIFT+UNDERSCORE",...]).

How can I get the corresponding keycodes of those strings?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it...
http://ibus.googlecode.com/svn-history/r177/docs/ibus/ibus-ibusshare.html#ibus-init

ibus_key_event_from_string () was the method I was looking for